# MySQL - Fetch rows where a field value is equal to foreach value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to only fetch data which is related to foreach value.but em getting empty result.$userid is an array, thats why i need to use for each  .Please correctify this or suggest any alternative approach.

```
   $user_id=$_POST['uid'];
    foreach($user_id as $user_idf){

    $sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"select *  from  profile  where uid='$user_idf'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $num=$row['country'];

        echo $num;
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem, you are doing it correctly.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I em getting empty results

Comment: This doesn't really seem to describe the problem or actually ask a question, so I did vote to close. I almost didn't just because you used the word "correctify" - that's awesome.

Comment: @CutyPie can you post the value of `$user_id`. May be it is empty. Use `print_r($user_id)` to view all data of `$user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one query to base is prefered. Also you've forgotten field `country` in you query. Try this way:

```
   $user_id=$_POST['uid'];
   $user_id = is_array($user_id)?$user_id:(array)$user_id;
   if(!empty($user_id)) {
       $sql=mysqli_query(
           $db3->connection,
           "select name, country from  profile 
            where uid in (".implode(', ', $user_id).")"
       );
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
           $num=$row['country'];
           echo $num;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Don't forget to escape the POST data.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher the question was not about validation data. But if we speak about validation the `intval` will be better than escaping. You need just add `$user_id = array_map('intval', $user_id)`

Comment: @Tyranron still emty results

Comment: @Cuty Pie ... than your $_POST parameter is wrong or not exists in base...or your field country not exists in base...you need to say exactly what you want to see - `country` or `name`?